# Add a varying range of data from a google sheet into an email via Google Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I've got a script that when run sends out an email with information taken from a Google Sheet. At the moment it is only in text form, but I would also like to add additional information in a table format (2 columns and a varying number of rows depending on how many rows of data there are).

Can someone please advise how I might be able to go about solving this?

Below is the current code being used:

```
function ClosedPOsEmail() {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 13 January 2021
  //  - add |range| in |e.range.rowStart|
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 13 January 2021
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/93209480
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 26 September 2020
  //  - initial version
  //  - see https://support.google.com/docs/thread/73381933?msgid=73395384
  

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Cancelled POs");
  var cancelledPOs = sheet.getRange("B6").getValue();
  var eaches = sheet.getRange("D6").getValue();
  var Date = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  var poBreakdown = sheet.getRange('B8');

  

  const emailAddress = 'toby.berry@email.com';
  const emailSubject = 'CONFIRMATION OF CLOSED PURCHASE ORDERS - '+ Date;
  let emailContents = 'Dear all,\n';
  emailContents += 'This is to confirm that ' + cancelledPOs + ' POs have been cancelled which consisted of ' + eaches+ ' eaches.\n\n';
  emailContents += poBreakdown + '\n\n';
  emailContents += 'Kind regards,\n';
  emailContents += 'Toby';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailContents);

  Browser.msgBox("The Cancelled POs email has now been sent. Thank you!");
```

These are the lines I've tried adding to do what I would like to do:

```
var poBreakdown = sheet.getRange('B8');

emailContents += poBreakdown + '\n\n';
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. Your problem is hard to understand. It's not clear whether you want help getting the data from the spreadsheet, or constructing the email, or sending the email. You mention two columns of data but your example references only one column.  You didn't include an example of the format of the email that you want to create. Would you please clarify EXACTLY what is your problem, and provide more information to enable users to assist you.

Comment: @Tedinoz, thank you for helping. For clarification, I'm trying to enter a table into the email that shows the information. At the moment I have it done like this:

`
The PO breakdown is as follows:
PO Number: 11574448 consisting of 0 eaches.
PO Number: 11573517 consisting of 0 eaches.
PO Number: 11591421 consisting of 36 eaches.
PO Number: 11589521 consisting of 32 eaches.
PO Number: 11586031 consisting of 12 eaches.`

This is pulled from sheet using the below formula for the 1st column:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(FILTER('Late Delivery Emails'!D:D,'Late Delivery Emails'!N:N=TRUE),""))`

Comment: Toby, you're only giving part of the story. _Edit your question to_ show some sample data_ (before and after your filter?) and show an example of what the outcome is supposed to look like.